# Construction of the word "подтвержда́ть"

Tags: словарь

I've heard that in Russian the words are generally constructed with a root and have specific prefixes or suffixes added to them (I think the proper linguistics term for this is derivational morphology)...

I'm trying to work out the construction of "подтвержда́ть " (imperf). From wikipedia I see that the etymology of the word is as such:

подтверди́ть  +‎ -а́ть

And the etymology of подтверди́ть is

под-  +‎ твёрдый +‎ -ить

под- (takes adjectives, produces adverbs) and means: completely
твёрдый means: hard or solid?
ить: to

So the meaning is like "to be completely solid/to be completely firm"?

I'm interested to know how a native Russian speaker would break down this word into the seperate parts and explain it.

Comment: Closer to “to make solid”.

Comment: The root for 'hard, solid' is present in Russian in the form of two etymological doublets: _-тверд-_ / _-твёрд-_ / _-твёрж-_ is of the East Slavic origin, and _-твержд-_ is borrowed from the (Old) Church Slavonic language. The change of the old *dj > žd is typical of the South Slavic languages, to which (Old) Church Slavonic belongs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- *под* is a prefix with the general meaning of "sub", "under", however its meaning can vary greatly.
- *твержд* is a root, loaned from Church Slavonic (you can tell by the *жд* as the reflex of the original Proto-Slavic **-dj-*, a native Russian word would have had *ж*).
- *-ать* is an inflexional ending, meaning this form is an infinitive

This word seems like a calque from Greek *ἐπιβεβαιῶ* "I confirm", from *ἐπί* "at" and *βέβαιος* "firm, steady".

Note that the English words "confirm" and "affirm" are Latin loanwords with the same structure.

Comment: подпольная организация:  an underground organization. "Pod" is very interesting. The answer above really hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the root morpheme of **подтверждать** is **твёрд** ('solid') (which has **твер(ж)д(ь)** as allomorphs).

The prefix **под-** can be loosely interpreted as 'to add':

- мешать (mix) - подмешать (to mix in)
- нести (bring) - поднести (to bring in), etc

So the whole word **подтверждать** can be read as 'to add solidity/weight' (to a statement).

One other word with the same root is **утверждать** which has two meanings: 'to make a statement' and 'to approve / sign off'.